# sort hash ref inside array ref perl

Tags: perl

i have the following structure...

```
 my $categories = { $category => [
                                  {
                                   id => 1,
                                   title => "title1",
                                   sort_order => 1
                                  },
                                  {
                                   id => 13,
                                   title => "title2",
                                   sort_order => 2
                                  },
                                  {
                                   id => 15,
                                   title => "title3",
                                   sort_order => 3
                                  }

 ] };
```

can anyone tell me if there is a way to sort the results based on sort_order?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set up a method for a sort() to use and make a new array from this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
my $category="wombats";

 my $categories = { $category => [
                                  {
                                   id => 1,
                                   title => "title1",
                                   sort_order => 1
                                  },
                                  {
                                   id => 13,
                                   title => "title2",
                                   sort_order => 2
                                  },
                                  {
                                   id => 15,
                                   title => "title3",
                                   sort_order => 3
                                  }

 ] };


my @sorted = sort { $a->{sort_order} <=> $b->{sort_order} } @{$categories->{$category}};

print "by sort_order\n";
print Dumper(@sorted);

my @sorted2 = sort { $b->{id} <=> $a->{id} } @{$categories->{$category}};

print "by reverse id\n";
print Dumper(@sorted2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is using `nsort_by` from [`List::UtilsBy`](http://metacpan.org/module/List::UtilsBy)

Here's an example. I've assumed that the key `$category` in your example data should be `category`

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::UtilsBy qw/ nsort_by /;

my $categories = {
    category => [
        {   id         => 1,
            title      => "title1",
            sort_order => 1
        },
        {   id         => 13,
            title      => "title2",
            sort_order => 2
        },
        {   id         => 15,
            title      => "title3",
            sort_order => 3
        },

    ]
};

my $list = $categories->{category};

for my $item ( nsort_by { $_->{sort_order} } @$list ) {

  printf "sort order: %d\n", $item->{sort_order};
  printf "id:         %d\n", $item->{id};
  printf "title:      %s\n", $item->{title};
  print "\n";
}
```

### output

```
sort order: 1
id:         1
title:      title1

sort order: 2
id:         13
title:      title2

sort order: 3
id:         15
title:      title3
```

However, if you don't have the module installed (it's not a core module) then you can do it with basic Perl like this with the same results

```
for my $item ( sort { $a->{sort_order} <=> $b->{sort_order} } @$list ) {

  printf "sort order: %d\n", $item->{sort_order};
  printf "id:         %d\n", $item->{id};
  printf "title:      %s\n", $item->{title};
  print "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sort` function allows you to apply arbitrary criteria to a sort, via a function.

This function should take `$a` and `$b` which are set to each record in turn. It should return `-1`, `0`, `+1` (or any positive/negative number - the sign is what is important) depending on relative position.

This is complicated a little by the depth of your nesting. You can sort with:

```
sort { $a -> {sort_order} <=> $b -> {sort_order} } @stuff;
```

Which will compare the values and give you an ordered result.

To get at that array from your data though, you need to dereference. `$category` is a variable in your example - did you mean to use that? Anyway given your thing:

```
 @{$categories -> {$category}}
```

So:

```
sort { $a -> {sort_order} <=> $b -> {sort_order} } @{$categories -> {$category}}
```

Which you can use in a `for` loop:

```
foreach my $thing ( sort { $a -> {sort_order} <=> $b -> {sort_order} } @{$categories -> {$category}} ) {
    print $thing -> {title},"\n";
}
```